# Git - How to save diff to file when diff.external tool is configured?

Tags: git, git-diff, meld

I've [configured my git to use Meld as the diff tool](http://nathanhoad.net/how-to-meld-for-git-diffs-in-ubuntu-hardy):

```
git config --global diff.external /home/myname/diff.py
```

When I'm trying to save a diff to a file by: `git diff > file.diff` Meld is opened and the diff is not saved.
How can I save the diff to a file without opening Meld?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `--no-ext-diff` option:

```
git diff --no-ext-diff > file.diff
```